# hyper-v , VMs have no internet access

Tags: hyper-v

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 with 2 NICs but only one IP address, which I have installed Hyper-V.  Inside of Hyper-V, I created 2 virtual machines.

I setup an external virtual network and chose the NIC that is bound to the IP address. I also checked the box that lets it share that port for internet access.

The physical server works great, has internet access, etc.  However, neither of the 2 virtual machines can access the internet.

Is there any other setting that I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: In Hyper-V Manager I added a "Network Adapter - Default Switch" and then the internet connection worked again on the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each virtual machine needs to have a virtual Network Adapter connected to the external virtual network. For each VM, check `Settings > Hardware > Network Adapter`.

Comment: mine says "Not Connected"

Answer (score 3):

Windows Server 2012 R2 as your Hyper-V main computer will ask you if you want to bind to a Ethernet and it works pretty well.

Windows 10 , you go to "Virtual Switch Manager"  , clicking on left side for your machine name and then "most" people say to add a "External" Virtual Switch,  ( Create a Virtual Switch)  but I have seen people say to use Internal.

Personally with Windows 8 years ago I did not have any issues,  recently I was losing my main machine internet with unchecking/checking the

```
Allow Management operating system to share this network adapter
```

Overall you shouldn't have too big a problem.  THEN, you are going to want to use the adapter in the virtual machine settings.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my VM connection issue with a `Network Reset` in Windows 10.

Ref: https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=70821